# Best iPad Tablet Model For DJI Drone Apps

Tags: tablet, apple, drone

From the first smartphones, I've always been an Android user, and have never owned a iOS based device. Every time I find myself trying to operate some function with someone's iPhone, it isn't pretty.

That said, for the first time, I need an iPad, and when I search for them on eBay, I have no idea what I'm looking at, and don't understand why the prices range so widely. I'd prefer a used device for no other reason than the value over new.

I own a small commercial drone services business with 3 aircraft in the fleet. The vast majority of the work conducted with drones require the use of a mobile device application. Most app developers offer both iOS and Android versions, with a few choosing to use iOS. However, in nearly every drone app I use, the iOS version of these Android apps are far more stable and feature-rich.

Here's the requirements:

1. 7"+ iOS tablet
2. WiFi Only, no cellular capabilities
3. Processing Power and RAM to ensure minimal risk of crashing when running drone ground control and mapping apps
4. $150 or less

Thanks!

Comment: Someone gave an answer which had a link to a fantastic chart which answered my question. It's gone now, and I don't know why. Please repost it!